# CMake fatal error: CMakeFiles/<path>.dir/main.cpp.d: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, g++

I am trying to compile a simple C++ program with CMake on Ubuntu 18.04, but all of my CMake projects fails when I run the `make` command.
Below is a minimum working example.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
- project directory
|-build
|-main.cpp
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
project(Test-Project)

add_executable(a
    main.cpp
)
target_compile_options(a
    PUBLIC -Wall -o -std=c++11
)
```

**Building**

```
cd build
cmake ../ # this works without any error
make  # this fails
```

**Error**

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.o
cc1plus: fatal error: CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.d: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/a.dir/build.make:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/a.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/a.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I get this error when try to compile any CMake based program on the system.
However, if I just used `g++` directly to compile the program, it compiles without any complaints.
For example:

```
g++ ../main.cpp
```

compiles the program, and runs the program without any errors.

- `cmake --version`: `cmake version 3.22.1`
- `g++ --version`: `g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`
- `g++ -print-prog-name=cc1plus`: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1plus`
- `uname -a`: `Linux <computer name> 5.4.0-91-generic #102~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP <date+time> x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**EDIT**

Terminal output when compiled with `make VERBOSE=1`:

```
/home/kani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -S/home/kani/Documents/test -B/home/kani/Documents/test/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/home/kani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/kani/Documents/test/build/CMakeFiles /home/kani/Documents/test/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kani/Documents/test/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/a.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kani/Documents/test/build'
cd /home/kani/Documents/test/build && /home/kani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/kani/Documents/test /home/kani/Documents/test /home/kani/Documents/test/build /home/kani/Documents/test/build /home/kani/Documents/test/build/CMakeFiles/a.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kani/Documents/test/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/a.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kani/Documents/test/build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -Wall -o -std=c++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/kani/Documents/test/main.cpp
cc1plus: fatal error: CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.d: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/a.dir/build.make:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/a.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kani/Documents/test/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/a.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/a.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kani/Documents/test/build'
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: can you build with `make VERBOSE=1` ?

Comment: Thank you, I just edited my original post with the output.

Comment: Option `-o` specifies an object file to be created as a result of the compilation. CMake sets this option automatically. Do not set `-o` option in CMake file: that way you damage the command line which is prepared by CMake.

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev. That was it. Deleting `-o` fixed it. I was confused since this gets compiled on a different computer. That one uses `CMake 3.10.2`. The one that failed uses `CMake 3.22.1`. May be something to do with the version. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: Unrelated:  `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` does the same but portably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the error message about absent `.d` file seems to be internal to CMake (such files are used for collect header dependencies generated by the compiler), its usual reason is specifying some **output-controlling compiler options** in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

In your case it is `-o` option which damages the command line generated by CMake. CMake by itself uses this option for specify object file which will be created as a result of the compilation. So adding another `-o` is wrong.